# \ifPDFTeX does not recognize pdflatex

Tags: pdftex

I downloaded `iftex` from CTAN and installed it.  I think I'm using it according to the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \errmessage{Don't use pdflatex.  Use plain latex and dvipdf}
\else
  \errmessage{Good. You aren't using pdflatex}
\fi
\end
```

However, this construct does not recognize `pdflatex` .  I get the message "Good. You aren't using pdflatex" whether I use `latex` or `pdflatex`.

```
$ latex iftex.tex
This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4)
entering extended mode
(./iftex.tex
LaTeX2e <2003/12/01>
Babel <v3.8d> and hyphenation patterns for american, french, german, ngerman, b
ahasa, basque, bulgarian, catalan, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, e
stonian, finnish, greek, icelandic, irish, italian, latin, magyar, norsk, polis
h, portuges, romanian, russian, serbian, slovak, slovene, spanish, swedish, tur
kish, ukrainian, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/iftex/iftex.sty)
! Good. You aren't using pdflatex.
l.6   \errmessage{Good. You aren't using pdflatex}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on iftex.log.
$
$ pdflatex iftex.tex
This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4)
entering extended mode
(./iftex.tex
LaTeX2e <2003/12/01>
Babel <v3.8d> and hyphenation patterns for american, french, german, ngerman,
[...]
nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/iftex/iftex.sty)
! Good. You aren't using pdflatex.
l.6   \errmessage{Good. You aren't using pdflatex}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on iftex.log.
$
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What system are you running this on? The sources seem outdated, including the compiler. I can't replicate your result on TeX Live 2018 with all content up-to-date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\ifPDFTEX` test is checking the *engine* in use (TeX90 vs pdfTeX vs XeTeX vs LuaTeX), not the output *format*. For that, you want the `ifpdf` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \errmessage{Don't use pdflatex.  Use plain latex and dvipdf}
\else
  \errmessage{Good. You aren't using pdflatex}
\fi
\end
```

Answer (score 3):

In recent TeX Distributions latex is actually a symbolic link (or the equivalent in systems that don't support symbolic links) to pdftex (actually pdfetex) which runs the latex format in dvi mode.